# Add a row (array) to an empty matrix

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix, row, addition

I would like to add a row (array) to an empty matrix.

Like adding an array to an empty array:

```
a = []
a << [1,2,3]

=> [[1,2,3]]
```

So I tried the following:

```
require 'Matrix'
m = Matrix[]
m.to_a << [1,2,3]

# => Matrix.empty(0, 0)
```

then the following:

```
m = Matrix[]
Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [1,2,3])

# => Matrix.empty(0, 0)
```

but it doesn't work! It should create following matrix:

```
# => Matrix[[1,2,3]]

# and then with each add:
# => Matrix[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], ...]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your problem? It works for me.

Comment: @JunZhou which version ruby you are using? as in Ruby 1.9.3 result is same as `OP`. Although I know why not working as expected?

Comment: @RubyLovely I use 1.9.3p392. The codes are posted as an answer. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine with Ruby 1.9.3p392

```
1.9.3p392 :001 > require 'matrix'
 => true 
1.9.3p392 :002 > m = Matrix[]
 => Matrix.empty(0, 0) 
1.9.3p392 :003 > m = Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [1,2,3])
 => Matrix[[1, 2, 3]] 
1.9.3p392 :004 > m = Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [2,3,4])
 => Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Also fine with 2.0.0p0

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > require 'matrix'
 => true 
2.0.0p0 :002 > m = Matrix[]
 => Matrix.empty(0, 0) 
2.0.0p0 :003 > m = Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [1,2,3])
 => Matrix[[1, 2, 3]] 
2.0.0p0 :004 > m = Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [2,3,4])
 => Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Ahh, I found the issue. I didn't reassign the adding to the matrix (variable m). Now it works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
m = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
matrix = Matrix.rows(m)

m << [4,5,6]
matrix = Matrix.rows(m)
```

Comment: Note that, technically, this is instantiating a new Matrix rather than "adding a row" to the existing one.  This can have both performance and subtle semantic implications which you should keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'Matrix'
m = Matrix[]
p m.object_id #=> 6927492
p m.to_a.class #=> Array
p m.class #=> Matrix
p m.to_a.object_id #=> 6927384
p m.to_a << [1,2,3] #[[1, 2, 3]]
p m #=> Matrix.empty(0, 0)
```

See above the `object_id` are diferrent. `m.to_a` don't convert the matrix `m` itself,rather it gives a new array representation of the given matrix.

Now in the below, `Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [1,2,3])` creates a new matrix,not adding any rows to `m` matrix itself. Thus `p m` showing the result as expected.

```
p Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [1,2,3]).class #=> Matrix
p Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [1,2,3]).object_id #=> 6926640
p Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [1,2,3]) #=>Matrix[[1, 2, 3]]
p m #=> Matrix.empty(0, 0)
```

Now to make it work do the below:

```
m = Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [1,2,3]) #=>Matrix[[1, 2, 3]]
p m #=>Matrix[[1, 2, 3]]
```